# Is it possible to be a frequentist and a subjectivist at the same time?

Tags: probability, statistics, philosophy

I'm trying to understand the differences between (1) Bayesian vs frequentist; and (2) subjectivist vs objectivist.

So far my understanding (correct me if I'm wrong) is that:

(1) Bayesian vs frequentist.

- Frequentist: A probability $p$ represents a long-run frequency.
- Bayesian: A probability $p$ simply reflects our tentative state of knowledge. Given new information, we may update $p$.

(2) Subjectivist vs objectivist.

- Subjectivist: A probability is simply one's personal, subjective degree of belief about some particular matter. So two rational, intelligent people with the same information and knowledge can disagree about a probability $p$.
- Objectivist: It is impossible for two perfectly-rational people with the same information and knowledge to disagree about a probability $p$.

My understanding is that Bayesians are typically subjectivist and frequentists are typically objectivist.

However, it is possible for Bayesians to be objectivist.

My question is this: **Is it possible for frequentists to be subjectivist?**  And how would such a subjectivist-frequentist interpret probability?

Comment: I have to say that this does not seem like a mathematics problem. Probably you should try the Cross Validated.

Comment: @Misakov: See [this meta thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9043), and the [tag:philosophy] tag (which I added to this question). There are some highly upvoted questions there such as "Is formal truth in mathematical logic a generalization of everyday, intuitive truth?" that are at least as philosophical as this one. I think a fair case can be made that this question is on-topic here.

Comment: @joriki you are definitely right. I'm just saying that OP probably would get better answers on Cross Validated :)

Comment: @Misakov. The point is that several algebraists and a programmer have voted to put what I view as a legit stat question on hold, thus denying OP the chance to get **any** answer here.